# how to use lftp for connecting to a ftps file server and pushing files to their server

Tags: ssl, lftp

we need to connect to one of the FTPS file server and push the files on a hourly basis. We are able to connect to their server using lftp after setting certificate, key files using set ssl:cert-file, ssl:key-file, but need help in sending files to their server using an automated shell script.

We have to follow below while connecting to their server (not sure how to follow these, while transferring commands and files to their server)

1. For Control channel we have to use one port (example port: 13021)
2. For Data channel we have to use other port range (example: 13100 to 13199)
3. For Transport Encryption we have to use 2048 bit Explicit SSL (control and data channel)

If any have tried it earlier, please share your inputs here.

The below screen shot conatains debug information for ls and put command. Put command is failed with error.
[image]

Comment: I am able to proceed, but I got stuck at put command, when I issue put command it is throwing "command not understood" error (screen shot is attached above). It might be because of I am trying to upload in un-encrypted data connection. I am not sure how to trouble shoot further. That image contains debug statements for put command failure  on lftp. That image contains debug information for ls and put commands.

Comment: I have made a good progress here, we are able to send the file to FTPS server, now it is failing when "SITE UTIME" command is issued to the server, and I could see SITE command in reply of FEAT command issued to server. This might be because of server does not support updating the files last access time. Is there a way we can disable issuing the SITE command for lftp client.

Comment: At last I am able to upload files to their server. I have followed below steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I am able to upload files to their server. I have set the below parameters in lftp session and it worked for me.

1. set ssl:cert-file /path/to/somecert.crt
2. set ssl:key-file /path/to/somekey.key
3. set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
4. set ftp:use-site-utime2 false